# Javascript : How convert existing JSON Object into custom key based Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I need to convert/destructure my existing JSON object into a new form with key-based JSON,
please look at the below input JSON

**Note : Below array has n numbers of Objects.**

INPUT JSON:

```
[
    {
        "processId": 95,
        "pid": "PID_0",
        "actionData": [
            {
                "actionId": 96,
                "action": "Sbend",
                "avg": 0.09134998917579651,
                "avgVid": "",
                "max": 0.13287270069122314,
                "maxVid": ",
                "maxPos": 1,
                "min": 0.06643635034561157,
                "minVid": "",
                "minPos": 0,
                "total": 8,
                "totalTime": null
            },
            {
                "actionId": 98,
                "action": "Stand",
                "avg": 0.7355453372001648,
                "avgVid": "",
                "max": 2.889981508255005,
                "maxVid": "",
                "maxPos": 11,
                "min": 0.06643635034561157,
                "minVid": "",
                "minPos": 9,
                "total": 28,
                "totalTime": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Here I need is take the 'pid' key value and set it to the root key for existing JSON,
Below there is an expected output

Expected OUTPUT

```
[
    "PID_0" : {
        "processId": 95,
        "actionData": [
            {
                "actionId": 96,
                "action": "Sbend",
                "avg": 0.09134998917579651,
                "avgVid": "",
                "max": 0.13287270069122314,
                "maxVid": ",
                "maxPos": 1,
                "min": 0.06643635034561157,
                "minVid": "",
                "minPos": 0,
                "total": 8,
                "totalTime": null
            },
            {
                "actionId": 98,
                "action": "Stand",
                "avg": 0.7355453372001648,
                "avgVid": "",
                "max": 2.889981508255005,
                "maxVid": "",
                "maxPos": 11,
                "min": 0.06643635034561157,
                "minVid": "",
                "minPos": 9,
                "total": 28,
                "totalTime": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Code I'm using to achieve this, but its not giving correct result to me,

```
let b = Object.keys(itemsValues).reduce(
  (p, c) => { console.log(p)
    for (let item of itemsValues[c].actionData) {
      p.pid.actionData.push(item);
    }
    return p;
  }, {
    pid: {
      actionData: [],
    },
  }
);
```

Kindly help me out to fix this issue, its really helps me a lot.
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you could, please post your code, expected behavior, and actual behavior.

Comment: Your expected output is wrong. Arrays can't have keys in Javascript. You expect an array with key-value.

Comment: the expected output is not valid JSON. `[ key: {} ]` is wrong. It should be `{ key: {} }`

Comment: here you go: https://tsplay.dev/NnaVxw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. reduce the array into the object you are looking for as output
2. set new key for object based on the received `pid`
3. then remove that `pid` from its original position

In terms of code:

```
const result = input.reduce((finalObject, obj) => {
    finalObject[obj.pid] = obj;
    delete obj.pid;
    return finalObject;
}, {});
```

Following is working snippet:

```js
const input = [{
  processId: 95,
  pid: 'PID_0',
  actionData: [{
      actionId: 96,
      action: 'Sbend',
      avg: 0.09134998917579651,
      avgVid: '',
      max: 0.13287270069122314,
      maxVid: '',
      maxPos: 1,
      min: 0.06643635034561157,
      minVid: '',
      minPos: 0,
      total: 8,
      totalTime: null,
    },
    {
      actionId: 98,
      action: 'Stand',
      avg: 0.7355453372001648,
      avgVid: '',
      max: 2.889981508255005,
      maxVid: '',
      maxPos: 11,
      min: 0.06643635034561157,
      minVid: '',
      minPos: 9,
      total: 28,
      totalTime: null,
    },
  ],
}, ];

const result = input.reduce((finalObject, obj) => {
  finalObject[obj.pid] = obj;
  delete obj.pid;
  return finalObject;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```